# By keeping only one entry, how can remove multiple occurrences of the special character

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How will I achieve below mentioned output.

I wanted to remove multiple occurrences of the **ONLY **special character **not words or digit. **

[Link to Original Image of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVRv8.png)

| Data | Output Needed |
| --- | --- |
| CL-LIN-VM--OE382F | CL-LIN-VM-OE382F |
| CYaIX-PHY--aG617A | CYalX-PHY-aG617A |
| FRWIN-VM--FO025B | FRWIN-VM-FO025B |
| PYWIN-VM--IK043D | PYWIN-VM-IK043D |
| MQAIX--PhQA622F | MQAIX-PhQA622F |

I tried this code but its replace all the value

```py
Single_Column['Workload_2'].replace(regex=True,
                                    inplace=True,
                                    to_replace=r"[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]",
                                    value=r'-')
```

Comment: Please remember to post your data as **text**, not images.

Comment: What's wrong with `df.Data.str.replace('--','-')`

Comment: If you don't want to replace words or digits, why does your regex replace string have `a-zA-Z0-9`?

Comment: Hello @Chris actually its dynamic some time  its came with 2 dash (-) some times its 7 dash(-) some times there is another special character like ? or ! That's y I also mentioned I have to remove all the special character multiple occurrence by keeping 1st entry as it is and excluding alphabet & digit

Comment: @JohnGordon Actually, I just figured it out—no need for this a-zA-Z0-9? Please bear with me as I am new to Python. Thank you!

Comment: @QuangHoang In the future, I will undoubtedly provide Meta Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "`[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]`" Pattern will select all values individually that are not present in given Range pattern, or equal to characters " " (Space) or "-" (Hyphen), because of this "--" value will never be Replaced since "-" (Hyphe) is present in pattern.

If you only remove "-" (Hyphen) from pattern, "--" (Double Hyphen) this will be considered as two separate "-" (Hyphen) and replace function will replace each "-" (Hyphen) once so you will again end up with Double "-" (Hyphen) i.e. Same Number of Hyphen that were originally present.

So add "+" Quantier at end of Set ([]). this will match One or more occurrences of pattern (token) found earlier in this case Pattern found using Set ([]) i.e. all Characters not present in Set ([]), and will give it to you as one single String or Match.

Heance Use This Pattern: `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+`
"^" will give characters that are not present in given Range pattern and/or equal to character " " (Space)
"+" matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

"+" will create a string of special characters irrespective of how many times it appears, so we just have to replace entire string at once with value that we want

**PS:**
You Can Use Below or Other Similar Site for Checking and Debugging Your Regex Patterns, on right side of site you can see Explanation and Matches.
Check that to understand how your pattern will work and give you results

**Website Link**: [regex101: build, test, and debug regex](https://regex101.com/)
**Regular Expression**: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/gm`
**Test String**:

> sadada$^%$^&$&--RE#$##%#rtewe---+#$%1soro#%$124093@#%$!0=?><:[3433165^$%#@5

**Result (All Matches)**:

> $^%$^&$&--
> #$#
> #%#
> ---+#$%
> #%$   @#%$!
> =?><:[   ^$%#@